# How can I detect which version of SQL (eg SQL 2008 or SQL Azure)

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I need to detect which version of SQL I am dealing with to perorm various tasks, I need specifically detect if I am on SQL 2008 or SQL Azure.

How can I do this with detection code written in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start might be:  [Programmatically detect SQL Server Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602677/programmatically-detect-sql-server-edition).

Comment: Thanks, SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('edition') returns "SQL Data Services" in SQL Azure CTP August 2009