# How do I verify SQL Server versions, Including version, service pack, cumulative update and patch

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have 250 VM's for different clients using different version of SQL server installed.

I ran the below command to get the details but the information was not successful

```
SELECT 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel'),
    SERVERPROPERTY ('edition'),  
    @@version, 
    SERVERPROPERTY('PatchLevel')
```

Can someone please help? I need the information for details like SQL Server version, service pack, cumulative update and patches installed to the server.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587077/how-do-i-check-for-the-sql-server-version-using-powershell

Answer (score 6):

Hope you need this.,

```
select @@VERSION
```

Hope this helps you.,

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS [MachineName], 
SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS [ServerName],  
SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName') AS [Instance], 
SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') AS [IsClustered], 
SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') AS [ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS], 
SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS [Edition], 
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS [ProductLevel],               -- What servicing branch (RTM/SP/CU)
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateLevel') AS [ProductUpdateLevel],   -- Within a servicing branch, what CU# is applied
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS [ProductVersion],
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion') AS [ProductMajorVersion], 
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMinorVersion') AS [ProductMinorVersion], 
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductBuild') AS [ProductBuild], 
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductBuildType') AS [ProductBuildType],       -- Is this a GDR or OD hotfix (NULL if on a CU build)
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateReference') AS [ProductUpdateReference], -- KB article number that is applicable for this build
SERVERPROPERTY('ProcessID') AS [ProcessID],
SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') AS [Collation], 
SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled') AS [IsFullTextInstalled], 
SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly') AS [IsIntegratedSecurityOnly],
SERVERPROPERTY('FilestreamConfiguredLevel') AS [FilestreamConfiguredLevel],
SERVERPROPERTY('IsHadrEnabled') AS [IsHadrEnabled], 
SERVERPROPERTY('HadrManagerStatus') AS [HadrManagerStatus],
SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath') AS [InstanceDefaultDataPath],
SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath') AS [InstanceDefaultLogPath],
SERVERPROPERTY('BuildClrVersion') AS [Build CLR Version];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response :)
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateLevel') AS [ProductUpdateLevel],
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion') AS [ProductMajorVersion], 
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMinorVersion') AS [ProductMinorVersion], 
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductBuild') AS [ProductBuild], 
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductBuildType') AS [ProductBuildType],       -- Is this a GDR or OD hotfix (NULL if on a CU build)
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateReference') AS [ProductUpdateReference], -- KB article number that is applicable for this build
This value are NULL
also service-pack and patches are missing. :(

Comment: You get the service pack, while you run @@version

Comment: Thank you for your response 
there is no service pack installed on server
can you help in getting patches for the server

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that gives you all the Server Properties available through the [`SERVERPROPERTY` system function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql).

You can run this on old SQL versions and if the Property didn't exist back then, the function will just safely return a NULL.

```
SELECT
     SERVERPROPERTY('BuildClrVersion') AS BuildClrVersion
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') AS [Collation]
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('CollationID') AS CollationID
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ComparisonStyle') AS ComparisonStyle
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') AS [ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS]
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS [Edition]
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('EditionID') AS EditionID
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS EngineEdition
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('FilestreamConfiguredLevel') AS FilestreamConfiguredLevel
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('FilestreamEffectiveLevel') AS FilestreamEffectiveLevel
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('FilestreamShareName') AS FilestreamShareName
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('HadrManagerStatus') AS HadrManagerStatus
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath') AS InstanceDefaultDataPath
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath') AS InstanceDefaultLogPath
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName') AS [Instance]
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('IsAdvancedAnalyticsInstalled') AS IsAdvancedAnalyticsInstalled
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') AS [IsClustered]
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled') AS [IsFullTextInstalled]
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('IsHadrEnabled') AS IsHadrEnabled
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly') AS [IsIntegratedSecurityOnly]
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('IsLocalDB') AS IsLocalDB
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('IsPolybaseInstalled') AS IsPolybaseInstalled
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('IsSingleUser') AS IsSingleUser
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('IsXTPSupported') AS IsXTPSupported
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('LCID') AS LCID
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('LicenseType') AS LicenseType
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS [MachineName]
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProcessID') AS [ProcessID]
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductBuild') AS ProductBuild
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductBuildType') AS ProductBuildType
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion') AS ProductMajorVersion
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMinorVersion') AS ProductMinorVersion
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateLevel') AS ProductUpdateLevel
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateReference') AS ProductUpdateReference
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS [ProductVersion]
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ResourceLastUpdateDateTime') AS ResourceLastUpdateDateTime
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ResourceVersion') AS ResourceVersion
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS [ServerName]
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('SqlCharSet') AS SqlCharSet
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('SqlCharSetName') AS SqlCharSetName
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('SqlSortOrder') AS SqlSortOrder
    ,SERVERPROPERTY('SqlSortOrderName') AS SqlSortOrderName
    ,@@VERSION AS [Version]
```